# Rename all files in multiple folders with some condition in single linux command os script.

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rename, file-rename

I have multiple folders with multiple files. I need to rename those files with the same name like the folder where the file stored with "_partN" prefix.

As example,

I have a folder named as "new_folder_for_upload" which have 2 files. I need to convert the name of these 2 files like,

new_folder_for_upload_part1
new_folder_for_upload_part2

I have so many folders like above which have multiple files. I need to convert all the file names as I describe above.

Can anybody help me to find out for a single linux command or script to do this work automatically?

Comment: What are the original names of the files? `part1` and `part2`, by any chance, or do you have to enumerate them?

Comment: And do you need the renamed files in the subfolders, or all on the top directory?

Comment: Sample of files like:
FineHowardMD_1490040273_tab17.pdf
HowardFineMD_1463582881_tab17.pdf

I need to change the file name with the parent directory name and "_partN"

Example:
new_folder_for_upload_part1.pdf
new_folder_for_upload_part2.pdf

Finally after completion this work, I need to store all files from all directory into a top directory.

Comment: Should the "part" numbers restart at 1 for each subdirectory, or be incremented continuously?

Comment: When you say "single command", you mean that you can't use an .sh script?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bash` shell, and assuming you want the file numbering to restart for each subdirectory, and doing the moving of all files to the top directory (leaving empty subdirectories). Formatted as script for easier reading:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    myfile=$(echo $file | sed "s@./@@")
    mydir=$(dirname "$myfile")
    if [[ $mydir != $lastdir ]]
    then
        NR=1
    fi
    lastdir=${mydir}
    mv "$myfile" "$(dirname "$myfile")_part${NR}"
    ((NR++))
done
```

Or as one-line command:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do myfile=$(echo $file | sed "s@./@@"); mydir=$(dirname "$myfile"); if [[ $mydir != $lastdir ]]; then NR=1; fi; lastdir=${mydir}; mv "$myfile" "$(dirname "$myfile")_part${NR}"; ((NR++)); done
```

**Beware.** This is *armed*, and will do a bulk renaming / moving of every file in or below your current work directory. Use at your own risk.

To delete the empty subdirs:

```
find . -depth -empty -type d -delete
```

Comment: Thank you DevSolar,

Your provided script worked for me.

Thank you for your help.